# Save truth array to file in bits format

Tags: javascript

How save truth array to file in bits format?

```
const symbolSize = 8;
const bits = [true,true,false,false,true,true];
const byteArray = new window[`Uint${symbolSize}Array`]([/* `bits` here, */21, 31]);
const blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/octet-stream"});

const binFileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: What is the `21, 31` for?

Comment: What's the end goal here? (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts In fact, this was unnessesery. :)

Comment: @matmo The goal is to find a method on how to save individual bits to a file. I assumed that it must be placed at least in a byte, that it can not be otherwise. In fact, I would like to have any length of a single bit string. And I do it only as part of experiments, for the future. And I do it only as part of experiments, for the future. This is not directly needed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function you can use. The optional `padLsd` argument determines how to deal with the last bits in the array, if the `length` is not a multiple 8.

The input array `bools` is required to contain strictly `true` and `false` only, but if you prefer not to have that requirement you can change `const bits` to be `bools.map(Boolean).map(Number)` instead:

```js
function byteArrayFromBits (bools, padLsd = false) {
  const BITS_PER_ELEMENT = 8
  const pad = padLsd ? 'padEnd' : 'padStart'
  const bits = bools.map(Number) // coerce booleans to 0s and 1s
  const bytes = bits.reduce((array, bit, index, bits) => {
    if (index % BITS_PER_ELEMENT === 0) {
      const bitString = bits.slice(index, index + BITS_PER_ELEMENT).join('')
      const byte = bitString.length < BITS_PER_ELEMENT
        ? bitString[pad](BITS_PER_ELEMENT, '0')
        : bitString

      array.push(parseInt(byte, 2))
    }

    return array
  }, [])

  return Uint8Array.from(bytes)
}

const bits = [true, true, false, false, true, true]
const byteArrayLSD = byteArrayFromBits(bits)
const byteArrayMSD = byteArrayFromBits(bits, true)

console.log(
  byteArrayLSD[0].toString(2),
  String.fromCharCode(...byteArrayLSD)
)
console.log(
  byteArrayMSD[0].toString(2),
  String.fromCharCode(...byteArrayMSD)
)
```